# Applying function across different columns

Tags: python

Playing around with the [538 masculinity survey](https://github.com/fivethirtyeight/data/tree/master/masculinity-survey).  Q0004 is broken into Q0004_001, Q0004_002, Q0004_003, and so on... The question is the following:

> Where have you gotten your ideas about what it means to be a good man? (Select all that apply.)
>
> Father or father figure(s)
> Mother or mother figure(s)
> Friends
> Other family members
> Pop culture

What's a more elegant way of writing the function shown below?

I defined the following function that applies across the columns.

```
def q0004_to_numeric(x):
    if x=='Not selected':                 return 0
    if x=='Father or father figure(s)':   return 1
    if x=='Mother or mother figure(s)':   return 1
    if x=='Other family members':         return 1
    if x=='Pop culture':                  return 1
    if x=='Friends':                      return 1
    if x=='Other (please specify)':       return 1

# Applying the function to the q0004 variable
masc_survey_response['q0004_0001'] = masc_survey_response['q0004_0001'].apply(q0004_to_numeric)
masc_survey_response['q0004_0002'] = masc_survey_response['q0004_0002'].apply(q0004_to_numeric)
masc_survey_response['q0004_0003'] = masc_survey_response['q0004_0003'].apply(q0004_to_numeric)
masc_survey_response['q0004_0004'] = masc_survey_response['q0004_0004'].apply(q0004_to_numeric)
masc_survey_response['q0004_0005'] = masc_survey_response['q0004_0005'].apply(q0004_to_numeric)
masc_survey_response['q0004_0006'] = masc_survey_response['q0004_0006'].apply(q0004_to_numeric)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **pandas.Dataframe.apply()** function in pandas to handle with multiple columns (in this case, your q0004_xxxx) and apply some useful things such as **lambda function**. Here is a code sample that you can try :

```
# code sample for applying function across columns that has q0004 as prefix 
masc_survey_response = masc_survey_response.apply(lambda x: q0004_to_numeric(x) if 'q0004' in x.name else x, axis=0)
```

Hope this help !

Comment: tried running and I got a _ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()._ Would you be able to clarify a bit?

Comment: You can use this link https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/applying-lambda-functions-to-pandas-dataframe/ as a handbook to solve your problem. However, if still get the same error, you can ask me again.

Comment: I tried this one but for some reason I'm stumped by the x.name which seems to be the problem for me.

Comment: It seems to be much complicated. I think it is much better to try this instead : masc_survey_response = masc_servey_response.loc[:, masc_survey_response.columns.str.contains(“q0004”)].apply(q0004_to_numeric)